# Scroll to HTML element with given name attribute in webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift

I'm using a `UIWebView` in swift that loads HTML from a database string using  `webView.loadHTMLString`

Here's a sample of the HTML I'm loading:

```
</p>\r\n<p>
<a name="bm001">**</a>
Physicists think the invisible dark matter must exist because they can see its\r\ngravitational effects on visible matter throughout the cosmos. But no one knows \r\nwhat it's actually made of. Among the leading candidates are weakly interacting \r\nmassive particles, or WIMPs, but scientists have <span style="color:red;">hunted for them for decades with \r\nno success</span>


</p>\r\n<p><a name="bm002"></a>
Theoretically, macros could have almost any size and mass. And because dark matter \r\ndoesn't interact with regular matter, there would be nothing to stop these particles \r\nfrom zipping around unimpeded. So Starkman - along with Case Western physicist Jagjit \r\nSingh Sidhu and physicist Robert Scherrer of Vanderbilt University in Nashville \r\n- decided to do a gut check using human flesh as a dark matter detector.</p>\r\n<p>If a macro as small as a square micrometer zipped through your body at hypersonic \r\nspeed, it would deposit about as much energy in your body as a typical metal bullet, \r\nthe team calculated. But the damage it caused would be different from that of a \r\nbullet: A macro would heat the cylinder of tissue in its wake to about  10,000,000&#176; \r\nCelsius - vaporizing the tissue and leaving a path of plasma.</p>

<p><a name="bm003"></a>Next, Starkman and Sidhu plan to look for macro tracks in slabs of granite, which \r\nwould appear as cylinders of black obsidian running straight through the rock. They're \r\nstarting with a cemetery near the Case Western campus.</p>
```

Now the functionality I want to achieve is to scroll to name tags with the press of buttons.
For ex. In the following HTML content there are three `<a>` tags containing different name i.e. `name="bm001",name="bm002",name="bm003"`

Now if I press on button1 then it will scroll to paragraph containing bm001,
if I press on button2 then it will scroll to paragraph containing bm002 and Similarly for other tags.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject JavaScript into your webview to perform the scroll operation, like this:

```swift
// Call this once when the page loads:

func setupPageScrolling() -> Bool {
  let functionJSCode = """
  function scrollToElement(name) {
     const element = document.querySelector("[name='" + name + "']");
     if (element == null) {
        console.log("cannot find element with name '" + name + "'");
        return false;
     }

     element.scrollIntoView({"behavior": "smooth"});
     return true;
  }

  typeof scrollToElement === "function"
  """

  return webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: functionJSCode) == "true"
}
```

Define a Swift function to call when you want to perform a scroll operation:

```swift
func scrollTo(name: String) -> Bool {
   return webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "scrollToElement('" + name + "')") == "true"
}
```

Call it as needed.

References:

[`UIWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617963-stringbyevaluatingjavascript)

[`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

---

### Full working example (tested with Xcode 11.3.1):

```swift
import UIKit

let html = """
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
        But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
      </p>
      
      <a name="foo">Link</a>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let webView = UIWebView()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.frame = self.view.bounds
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}

extension ViewController : UIWebViewDelegate {
    func setupPageScrolling() -> Bool {
      let functionJSCode = """
      function scrollToElement(name) {
         var element = document.querySelector("[name='" + name + "']");
         if (element == null) {
            console.log("cannot find element with name '" + name + "'");
            return false;
         }

         element.scrollIntoView({"behavior": "smooth"});
         return true;
      }

      typeof scrollToElement === "function"
      """

      return webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: functionJSCode) == "true"
    }
    
    func scrollTo(name: String) -> Bool {
       return webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "scrollToElement('" + name + "')") == "true"
    }
    
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        guard setupPageScrolling() else {
            print("Couldn't setup page scrolling JS function!")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
            guard self.scrollTo(name: "foo") else {
                print("Couldn't scroll to element with name \"foo\"")
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO VIDEO**: https://share.getcloudapp.com/KouWqlkG

Comment: I tried the code but nothing is happening on calling function.

Comment: If you want I can send the whole html content.

Comment: @ShresthaGoyal see updated answer - i have verified that it works for me.